# Find Min in rows in SQL table

Tags: sql, database, select, db2

I am trying to find all the clubs in my database that appear the least number of times in the database and display that club name and how many times it appeared. Below is my solution for what I tried

```
select club, MIN(num) 
from 
    (select count(club) as num 
     from member 
     order by club)
```

But this code throws an error:

> SQL0119N  An expression starting with "CLUB" specified in a SELECT clause, HAVING clause, or ORDER BY clause is not specified in the GROUP BY clause or it is in a SELECT clause, HAVING clause, or ORDER BY clause with a column function and no GROUP BY clause is specified.

I am new to SQL - can someone please tell me what is wrong and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`fetch first n rows only`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/perf/src/tpc/db2z_fetchfirstnrows.html) syntax:

```
SELECT      club, COUNT(*)
FROM        members
GROUP BY    club
ORDER BY    2 ASC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: It works. thanks alot. but could you explain a little what is going on in the order by and fetch?

Comment: @NewProgrammer7 The `order by` clause specifies the sorting you want the data sorted (ordered) in - here it's by the second column - the count (hence `2`), and in ascending order (hence `asc`). The `fetch first...` clause is pretty straight forward. So by saying "order by results according in an ascending order of count and fest just the first one`, you effectively get the row with the minimum count.

Comment: @NewProgrammer7 - Warning!  This is going to return exactly one row.  If there are multiple clubs with the same number of members, it will only show one of them, **AND** you may get a different one each time.

Answer (score 0):

You're heading in roughly the right direction.  You need to do a double-aggregate.

```
WITH Member_Count AS (SELECT club, COUNT(*) AS counted
                      FROM Members
                      GROUP BY club)
SELECT club, counted
FROM Member_Count 
WHERE counted = (SELECT MIN(counted)
                 FROM Member_Count)
```